# Understanding curvature as rate of change of angle between neighbouring tangents

Tags: differential-geometry

When introducing the concept of curvature in "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces", do Carmo makes the statement

> the norm $|\alpha''(s)|$ of the second derivative measure the rate of change of the angle which neighbouring tangents make with the tangent at $s$.

Here $\alpha(s)$ is a curve parametrized by arc length.

I have read similar things elsewhere, e.g. [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_plane_curves)

> the curvature of a plane curve at any point is the limiting ratio of $d\theta$, an infinitesimal angle (in radians) between tangents to that curve at the ends of an infinitesimal segment of the curve, to the length of that segment $ds$, i.e., $d\theta/ds$. If the tangents at the ends of the segment are represented by unit vectors, it is easy to show that in this limit, the magnitude of the difference vector is equal to $d\theta$, which leads to the given expression in the second definition of curvature.

Accompanying this is the following potentially useful diagram:

[image: test]

I cannot understand how to make this interpretation rigorous. In particular, interpreting do Carmo at face value, if we define $\theta_{s_0}(s)$ to be the angle between $\alpha'(s)$ and $\alpha'(s_0)$ for some fixed $s_0$, then

$$\theta_{s_0}(s) = \arccos\left[\alpha'(s) \cdot \alpha'(s_0)\right]$$

(since $||\alpha'(s)|| = 1$). However, this has derivative

$$\theta_{s_0}'(s) = -\frac{\alpha'(s_0) \cdot \alpha''(s)}{\sqrt{1 - (\alpha'(s) \cdot \alpha'(s_0))^2}},$$

which I do not believe is equal to $||\alpha''(s_0)||$.

Can anyone explain do Carmo's comment or the Wikipedia passage in precise terms?

Comment: This page might help: http://brickisland.net/cs177fa12/?p=187

Comment: It’s common when working with “infinitesimal” angles to replace $\sin d\theta$ by $d\theta$ and $\cos d\theta$ by $1$. Perhaps that will get to you an expression that looks more like the formula for curvature.

Comment: I've just asked the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336751/why-does-the-tangent-vector-measure-the-rate-of-change-of-the-angle-which-neighb

Comment: But $\theta'_{s_0}(s)$ is exactly $\Vert \alpha''(s)\Vert$. You almost proved that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the tangent $\alpha'(s)$ as the function $\alpha'(s)=(\cos\theta(s),\sin\theta(s))$ where $\theta(s)$ is the angle the tangent at $s$ makes with the horizontal line.

Let $n(s)$ be the normal vector as defined by Do Carmo, i.e, $n(s)$ is the unit vector perpendicular to $\alpha'(s)$ at $s$ such that $n(s)$ and $\alpha'(s)$ has a positive orientation. Note we have $|\alpha''(s)|=\langle\alpha''(s),n(s)\rangle$, since $\alpha''(s)$ is a multiple of the vector $n(s)$ at $s$.

Thus we have

$\alpha'(s)=(\cos\theta(s),\sin\theta(s))$

$\implies \alpha''(s)=\theta'(s)(-\sin\theta(s),\cos\theta(s))=\theta'(s)n(s)$

$\implies |a''(s)|=\langle \alpha''(s),n(s)\rangle=\theta'(s)$

Comment: As I understand it, the equality $\alpha'(s)=(\cos\theta(s),\sin\theta(s))$ should be interpreted as $\alpha'(s)=\cos\theta(s)\alpha^\prime(s_0)+\sin\theta(s)\alpha^{\prime\prime}(s_0)$. It seems this approach does not generalize to 3D, since $\alpha^\prime(s)$ need not be in the span of $\alpha^\prime(s_0),\alpha^{\prime\prime}(s_0)$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$\theta_{s_0}'(s) = -\dfrac{\alpha'(s_0) \cdot \alpha''(s)}{\sqrt{1 - (\alpha'(s) \cdot \alpha'(s_0))^2}}$

By definition of $\theta$, $\alpha'(s)\cdot\alpha'(s_0)=\Vert\alpha'(s)\Vert\Vert\alpha'(s_0)\Vert\cos\theta=\cos\theta$

Now, $\alpha'(s_0) \cdot \alpha''(s)=\Vert\alpha'(s_0)\Vert \Vert\alpha''(s)\Vert\cos\gamma$

But $\alpha'(s)$ and $\alpha''(s)$ are perpendicular and $\alpha''(s)$ positive for $\theta'_{s_0}$ positive, then, $\gamma=\pi/2+\theta$ and $\cos(\pi/2+\theta)=-\sin\theta$

$\alpha'(s_0) \cdot \alpha''(s)=-\Vert\alpha'(s_0)\Vert \Vert\alpha''(s)\Vert\sin\theta=-\Vert\alpha''(s)\Vert\sin\theta$.

Substituting in the expression for $\theta'_{s_0}(s)$

$\theta'_{s_0}(s)=-\dfrac{-\Vert\alpha''(s)\Vert\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}}=\Vert\alpha''(s)\Vert$